# How do I avoid nested maps to get the values I need from nested arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, lodash

I am doing something like this to get the values I need:

```
   tableRowsItems = data.softy.map(row =>
      row.items.map(item => console.log('item', item)),
    );
```

With that, I get something like in the picture below which is exactly what I need

[image]

My question is if that is the proper ES6 way to do it.
I am also using lodash if that helps.

This is how the json file looks without the map:

```
[
 {
  "ticketId": 67973802,
  "account": null,
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 11705294,
      "billingItemId": 361643044,
      "cancellationRequestId": 17289674,
      "immediateCancellationFlag": true,
      "scheduledCancellationDate": null,
      "serviceReclaimStatusCode": "COMPLETE",
      "billingItem": {
        "description": "Storage as a Service",
        "recurringFee": 0,
        "id": 361643044
      }
    }
  ]
 },
 ...
]
...
```

What I need is what you see on `items` key

Comment: so you're trying to get all `items` from each `ticket` into a single array?

Comment: It's not the right way, because you aren't `return`ing anything significant from either `.map` - use `forEach` instead, for generic iteration + side effects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using **ES6** you can easily do one line function to help you flatten the nested array by the `items` property via [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
var tickets = [{ "ticketId": 67973802, "account": null, "items": [{ "id": 117052912, "billingItemId": 36164304123, }, { "id": 11705232, "billingItemId": 361643044, }] }, { "ticketId": 67973802, "account": null, "items": [{ "id": 117052945, "billingItemId": 361643046, }, { "id": 117052953, "billingItemId": 361643049, }] } ];
 
const pullBy = (arr, prop) => arr.reduce((r,c) => [...r[prop], ...c[prop]])
 
console.log(pullBy(tickets, 'items'))
```

Using `lodash` the best option is [flatMap](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#flatMap):

```js
var tickets = [{ "ticketId": 67973802, "account": null, "items": [{ "id": 117052912, "billingItemId": 36164304123, }, { "id": 11705232, "billingItemId": 361643044, }] }, { "ticketId": 67973802, "account": null, "items": [{ "id": 117052945, "billingItemId": 361643046, }, { "id": 117052953, "billingItemId": 361643049, }] } ];
 
const result = _.flatMap(tickets, 'items')
 
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you're trying to extract all nested `items` from your array of `ticket` objects - in which case you can achieve this by mapping the input tickets to an array of `items` arrays, and then flatten the result to squish that down to a flat a array of `item` objects like so:

```
var output = input
.map(ticket => ticket.items) // Map each ticket to array of ticket items
.flat(); // Reduce array of item arrays to combined array of items
```

```js
var input = [
{
  "ticketId": 67973802,
  "account": null,
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 11705294,
      "billingItemId": 361643044,
      "cancellationRequestId": 17289674,
      "immediateCancellationFlag": true,
      "scheduledCancellationDate": null,
      "serviceReclaimStatusCode": "COMPLETE",
      "billingItem": {
        "description": "Storage as a Service",
        "recurringFee": 0,
        "id": 361643044
      }
    }
  ]
 },
 {
  "ticketId": 67973802,
  "account": null,
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 11705294,
      "billingItemId": 361643044,
      "cancellationRequestId": 17289674,
      "immediateCancellationFlag": true,
      "scheduledCancellationDate": null,
      "serviceReclaimStatusCode": "COMPLETE",
      "billingItem": {
        "description": "Storage as a Service",
        "recurringFee": 0,
        "id": 361643044
      }
    }
  ]
 }
 ];
 
 var output = input.map(ticket => ticket.items).flat();
 
 console.log(output);
```

Comment: Just a note that [`Array.flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat#Browser_compatibility) is an experimental feature and is not supported very well yet. If this is to be run within a web browser, you might want to [explore alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays-in-javascript).

Comment: For those of you coming here in 2022, `Array.flat` has pretty solid compatibility with all major browsers except IE  https://caniuse.com/array-flat

Answer (score 2):

Lodash has [`flatMap`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#flatMap) (the [native](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) JS version is not yet supported on all browsers) and you can use it as:

```
var items = _.flatMap(tickets, t => t.items);
```

to get all `items` from all tickets in a single 1-d array:

```js
var tickets = [{
    "ticketId": 67973802,
    "account": null,
    "items": [{
      "id": 117052912,
      "billingItemId": 36164304123,
    }, {
      "id": 11705232,
      "billingItemId": 361643044,
    }]
  },
  {
    "ticketId": 67973802,
    "account": null,
    "items": [{
      "id": 117052945,
      "billingItemId": 361643046,
    }, {
      "id": 117052953,
      "billingItemId": 361643049,
    }]
  }
];

var items = _.flatMap(tickets, t => t.items);
console.log(items);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Above answers will help you to achieve the goal but we use `.map` when we want to return something from the looping, otherwise you should use `forEach`.

I know it is really irrelevent to given questions but still. wanted to put it into the thread.